# how to overload std::ceil() in my program

Tags: c++, overloading, std, eigen, ceil

I use my own data type in Eigen lib by template,and I realize +-*/ overload , but Eigen use std::ceil() function, I don't know how to overload this.
thanks for every suggestion.

just tell me How to realize this method or some other ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Just replace the name "swap" with "ceil"

Comment: It seems that Eigen calls `ceil` after adding `using std::ceil;`. If you define `ceil` for your custom type in the same namespace, Eigen should be able to use it.